# Scroll horizontally on mobile for only some containers and not for entire page

Tags: html, css

I need some cards to be scrolled horizontally, but the rest of the page scroll vertically for mobile devices (which will be implemented later into mobile app). When I use dev tools for mobile version everything seems to work. But when I'm opening on my phone everything scrolls horizontally and not just the container. Here is the example: 
https://codepen.io/Ilima/pen/EdYYZP 
How can I accomplish this?

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scroll {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 240px;
  width:calc(100% -5px);
  background-color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  
}
.test {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.test p {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <p style="overflow-y: auto;">This should not scroll horizontally on mobile</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're SO close. The width of the scroll container is impacting the overall width of the body on mobile. Because `.scroll` has a percentage width, that means it is relative to the parent width.

What you want to do is make sure the width of the html/body do not exceed the viewport width.

```
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Adding that will make sure the body does not exceed the width of the viewport and then the scrolling should work as you expect on mobile. You can also set `width: 100vw;` on the `.scroll` container and it will work as expected too. Since this is going to mobile you are probably better off setting html/body though.

Comment: Oh my God, I spent all day for this... And this .... the little code ... but yet so important! This code fixed all of my issues. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: That was my entire day 

Answer (score 0):

Or ... use a media query to just "undo" the scroll on larger screens.

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```